# How to get listbox items one by one in c#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to Add ListBox items to XML file. I have one listBox[Maximum 10 items] that take value from TextBox. My program is working proper if listbox can have only 10 items, if listBox can have less than 10 items it wont Excute.

My Question is : if the listBox have 5 items it should update in the XML file.. How to do that ??
 [ For Eg: If listbox is have only 2 items When SAVE button press 2 item will be Saved in the XML file..   123456 
 123456     ..... Etc

My Program is as Follows :

```
private SOTA_whitelist_Number RetrieveSOTAConfiguration()
{
    string Number1;
    string Number2;
    Number1 = ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items[0].ToString();
    Number2 = ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items[1].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("\n Print Number1 and Number2 {0}, {1}", Number1, Number2);
    return new SOTA_whitelist_Number(Number1, Number2);
}
```

**UPDATE :**

Now i'm changed RetriveSOTAConfiguration() Function :

```
string[] Number;
        private SOTA_whitelist_Number RetrieveSOTAConfiguration()
        {

            int i = 1;

            for (i = 1; i <= ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n Print Number {0}", Number[i]);
                Number[i] = ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items[i].ToString();
            }

            return new SOTA_whitelist_Number(Number);
        }
```

**SOTA_whitelist_Number Class :** im not getting any idea how to change this code..

```
namespace iWave_Configuration_Tool.Models
{
    public class SOTA_whitelist_Number : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {        
        string Number1;
        string Number2;

        st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number whitelist_Number;

        //Constructors
        public SOTA_whitelist_Number()
        {
        }

        public SOTA_whitelist_Number(string Number1, string Number2)
        {
            this.whitelist_Number = new st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number(Number1.ToCharArray(), Number2.ToCharArray());

            this.Number1 = Number1;
            this.Number2 = Number2;
        }

        //Setter and Getters
        public string NUMBER1
        {
            set { Number1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Number1"); }
            get { return Number1; }
        }
        public string NUMBER2
        {
            set { Number2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Number2"); }
            get { return Number2; }
        }
        //Methods  
        public void PrintSOTAConfiguration()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n NUMBER1: {0}", NUMBER1);
            Console.WriteLine("\n NUMBER2: {0}", NUMBER2);
        }
        public st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number getStructure()
        {
            return whitelist_Number;
        }

        public void setSOTAwhitelist_Number(st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number whitelist_Num)
        {
            NUMBER1 = whitelist_Num.NUMBER1;
            NUMBER2 = whitelist_Num.NUMBER2;
        }

        //PAYLOAD STRUCTURE
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
    public struct st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number
    {
        char[] Number1;
        char[] Number2;
        ushort payload_length;

        //Constructor
        public st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number(char[] Number1, char[] Number2)
        {
            this.Number1 = new char[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ];
            this.Number2 = new char[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER2_STR_SZ];

            Common.InitToZero(ref  this.Number1);
            Common.InitToZero(ref this.Number2);

            Array.Copy(Number1,  this.Number1,  Number1.Length);
            Array.Copy(Number2,  this.Number2,  Number2.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Constructor..");
            this.payload_length = CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ + CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER2_STR_SZ;
        }

        //Setter and Getter
        public string NUMBER1
        {
            set { 
                Number1 = value.ToCharArray();
                Console.WriteLine("SETTER AND GETTER");
            }
            get { return Common.TRIM(Number1); }
        }
        public string NUMBER2
        {
            set { Number2 = value.ToCharArray(); }
            get { return Common.TRIM(Number2); }
        }

        public ushort LENGTH
        {
            get { return payload_length; }
        }

        //Methods
        //Method to convert the structure to byte array
        public byte[] ToByteArray()
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[LENGTH];

            byte[] Number1 = new byte[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ];
            byte[] Number2 = new byte[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER2_STR_SZ];

            Number1 = Common.CharArrayToByteArray(this.Number1);
            Number2 = Common.CharArrayToByteArray(this.Number2);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(Number1, 0, b, 0, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(Number2, 0, b, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER2_STR_SZ);

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nIn Buffer.BlockCopy Method.. ");
            return b;
        }

        //method to convert the buffer to structure
        public static st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number BufferToPayload(byte[] buffer)
        {
            st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number st = new st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number();
            st.Number1 = new char[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ];
            st.Number2 = new char[CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER2_STR_SZ];

            char[] chArray = Common.ByteArrayToCharArray(buffer);

            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, st.Number1, 0, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ);
            Array.Copy(chArray, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ, st.Number2, 0, CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER2_STR_SZ);
            Console.WriteLine("\n In Array.Copy Method.");
            st.payload_length = CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER1_STR_SZ + CommandDefine.MAX_SIZE.MAX_NUMBER2_STR_SZ;
            return st;
        }
        public void PrintSOTAConfiguration()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n NUMBER1: {0}", NUMBER1);
            Console.WriteLine("\n NUMBER2 : {0}", NUMBER2);
        }
    }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your updated RetrieveSOTAConfiguration will always crash. Why are you running a one-based for-loop? And what is the logic behind the whitelisting methods taking exactly two numbers? Which numbers are those? Two consecutive numbers from the ListBox items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>First of all make your `SOTA_whitelist_Number` independent of the number of parameters by making it accept an array of strings:</s>

```
SOTA_whitelist_Number(string[] numbers)
{
   ...
}
```

Then you can use Linq to get an array of phone numbers by:

`string[] numbers = ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();`

And then you simply invoke your new whitelist method:

`SOTA_whitelist_Number(numbers);`

or with all in place:

`SOTA_whitelist_Number(ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray(););`

**UPDATE** since the OP is changing the requirements.
Currently, those are as follows:

- there is a list of *phone numbers*
- a number of those *phone numbers* is selected into a *listbox*
- upon hitting a submit button an XML should be produced containing elements (each element name is "Number{id}" where *id* is a consecutive number) for every phone number in the initial list and the value filled only for the *phone numbers* existing in the listbox.

This code snippet with some predefined data should suffice:

```
List<string> phoneNumbers = new List<string>()
{
    "731-938-1205",
    "578-752-9997",
    "232-358-3643",
    "143-194-0427",
    "942-120-3607",
    "955-813-3178",
    "235-472-2789",
    "431-269-8378",
    "976-262-8301",
    "400-518-7667",
    "453-558-6838",
    "556-932-4148",
    "912-125-4605",
    "522-328-4712",
    "698-243-8591",
    "729-411-8117",
    "213-745-8236",
    "331-226-7769",
    "346-429-1049",
};

List<string> listbox = new List<string>()
{
    phoneNumbers[2],
    phoneNumbers[4],
    phoneNumbers[8]
};

private void GenerateXML()
{ 
    System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
    xmlWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
    xmlWriter.Indentation = 4;
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PhonesList");
    phoneNumbers.
        Select((n, i) => new Tuple<int, string>(i, n)).
        ToList().
        ForEach(t => 
        {
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement($"Number{(t.Item1 + 1).ToString()}");
            xmlWriter.WriteRaw(listbox.Contains(t.Item2) ? t.Item2 : string.Empty);
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        });

    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.Flush();
}
```

Now:

- `List<string> phoneNumbers` should be replaced with the actual list of the phone numbers
- `List<string> listbox` is the list of the numbers in the listbox, can be obtained by `List<string> listbox = ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList()`
- instead producing the XML to the console (`XmlTextWriter(Console.Out)`) it should be written to file, have a look the `XmlTextWriter` overloads
- `private void GenerateXML()` can be made an event handler for the 'Submit' button click, however I'd suggest making it async (won't freeze UI) and building in some exception handling (so it won't crash the code)

By running the above code the following output is produced:

```
<PhonesList>
    <Number1></Number1>
    <Number2></Number2>
    <Number3>232-358-3643</Number3>
    <Number4></Number4>
    <Number5>942-120-3607</Number5>
    <Number6></Number6>
    <Number7></Number7>
    <Number8></Number8>
    <Number9>976-262-8301</Number9>
    <Number10></Number10>
    <Number11></Number11>
    <Number12></Number12>
    <Number13></Number13>
    <Number14></Number14>
    <Number15></Number15>
    <Number16></Number16>
    <Number17></Number17>
    <Number18></Number18>
    <Number19></Number19>
</PhonesList>
```

Comment: Why does your st_SOTA_Whitelist_Number(char[] Number1, char[] Number2) need exactly two numbers? Are you forced to whitelist two numbers at a time? Perhaps it's better get the numbers from your listbox, group them by two and whitelist those pairs? And what about a situation when you have odd amount of entries? Please, share some context and not the source code only.

Comment: im taking listbox items based on thier index value, So When application run i add only on item to listbox and then press submit button is shows an Exceptions.            "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"

Comment: I want a code like, if im adding 1 item to listbox then press submit it have to be save in xml file. In my program i have total 20 Numbers.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your listbox has only one item at a time. This is why ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items[1] throws a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Is your goal to store each phone number in a separate XML file? Perhaps the best would be to rephrase your question.

Comment: no, in one XML file all Numbers will be store. eg : <Number1>999999999</Number1><Number2></Number2><Number3></Number3>.. Etc . if 3 number will be there in listbox then in xml file number1,2,3 Tag will be filled, Other tag will be empty

Comment: So let me wrap it up - you have a list of phone numbers. From this list you select some numbers, put them into a listbox and you're expecting an XML containing a tag for each number from the initial list with the values filled only for the numbers in the listbox?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. i want my output like this..  Can you modify it in my Code, please.. For xml i have seperate code.

Comment: I've already updated my answer, is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah, same thing i want, Is it possible to modify in my code

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the ListBox items and do what you need to do.

You can add an IF statement to skip this if more than 10 to suit your requirements.

```
foreach(ListItem item in ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items)
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Do you have Number3, Number4, all the way up to 10? If you don't then you can change to for loop with i = 0 to listBox.Items.Count then if i=1 then set that way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop each of the items in the list box.

```
foreach(var item in ListBox_PhoneNumber.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n Print Number {0}", item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Which Value i have to pass in ---> return new SOTA_whitelist_Number(Number1, Number2) Function.